# Give access to CloudFlare IPs in iptables

Tags: linux, networking, centos, firewall, iptables

I trying to `DROP` all requests except CloudFlare requests, and give SSH access to a certain ip.

so I write this rules :

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s x.x.x.x/32 --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 103.21.244.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 103.22.200.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 103.31.4.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 104.16.0.0/12 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 108.162.192.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 131.0.72.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 141.101.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 162.158.0.0/15 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 172.64.0.0/13 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 173.245.48.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 188.114.96.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 190.93.240.0/20 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 197.234.240.0/22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -s 198.41.128.0/17 -j ACCEPT
```

But after applying this rules, I can not access the server anymore even SSH.

I have CentOS 7 and so disabled `firewalld` and enabled `iptables` according to this article:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-from-firewalld-to-iptables-on-centos-7

my web server is `nginx` with `php-fpm`

Comment: your iptables rules are lacking stateful catch-all entries. Firewalld did add them automatically and you have to do the same. Complete your documentation: https://www.booleanworld.com/depth-guide-iptables-linux-firewall/#The_connection_tracking_module